# How to get address of variable in inline asm of Visual Studio

Tags: variables, assembly, visual-c++, sse, inline-assembly

I'm learning inline assembler in Visual Studio environment.
So, I'm implementing a simple dot product function and I cant seem to find a proper way to return a float result.

```
float dot(vec3 &a,vec3 &b)
{
    float result;
    float *p_result=&result;
    _asm
    {
        mov eax,dword ptr a
        mov ebx,dword ptr b
        movups xmm0,[eax]
        movups xmm1,[ebx]
        mulps xmm0,xmm1
        movaps xmm1,xmm0
        shufps xmm1,xmm1,0b1h
        addps xmm1,xmm0
        movaps xmm2,xmm1
        shufps xmm2,xmm2,02h
        addps xmm2,xmm1
        mov eax,dword ptr p_result
        movss [eax],xmm2
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way I could pass the declaration of `float` result and `float *p_result` in my function?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl)?  It talks about how to return floats (using st0).

Comment: The way to go with Visual Studio is to use intrinsics. MS does not allow inline assmebly in 64-bit mode anymore.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Don't use the EBX register if you can use EAX, ECX or EDX. According to the [cdecl calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions) are EBX, ESI and EDI callee-saved, i.e. the function has to return them unchanged. Visual Studio manages storage and recovery of these registers if necessary, but that's an unnecessary efford.

You don't need a pointer to the result. The inline assembler can directly access a local variable. furthermore you do not need a size directive (`DWORD PTR`) if the assembler can recognize the appropriate size.

```
float dot(vec3 &a,vec3 &b)      // no ebx, no pointer, no size directive
{
    float result;
    _asm
    {
        mov eax,a
        mov edx,b
        movups xmm0,[eax]
        movups xmm1,[edx]
        mulps xmm0,xmm1
        movaps xmm1,xmm0
        shufps xmm1,xmm1,0b1h
        addps xmm1,xmm0
        movaps xmm2,xmm1
        shufps xmm2,xmm2,02h
        addps xmm2,xmm1
        movss result,xmm2
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can omit the return line if you specify the return value yourself. Eventually you get a warning, but the function will return properly. If the return value is a float, it has to be in ST(0) of the FPU.

```
float dot(vec3 &a,vec3 &b)      // omit return, set ST(0) manually
{
    float result;
    _asm
    {
        mov eax,a
        mov edx,b
        movups xmm0,[eax]
        movups xmm1,[edx]
        mulps xmm0,xmm1
        movaps xmm1,xmm0
        shufps xmm1,xmm1,0b1h
        addps xmm1,xmm0
        movaps xmm2,xmm1
        shufps xmm2,xmm2,02h
        addps xmm2,xmm1
        movss result,xmm2
        fld result
    }
}
```

The compiler produces additional code at the begin and the end of the function, called "prologue" and "epilogue". You can bypass the epilogue (`leave` - `ret`), but this is incredibly dirty, because you don't know exactly what the prologue has done. To bypass both, prologue and epilogue, declare the function as [`naked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cpp/naked-cpp) and use `ESP` as base pointer. Still you need memory to transfer the result of XMM to the FPU. I use the first of the passed variable for that - it is nowhere needed anymore.

```
__declspec(naked) float dot(vec3 &a,vec3 &b)    // naked
{
    _asm
    {
        mov eax,[esp+4]             ; a
        mov edx,[esp+8]             ; b
        movups xmm0,[eax]
        movups xmm1,[edx]
        mulps xmm0,xmm1
        movaps xmm1,xmm0
        shufps xmm1,xmm1,0b1h
        addps xmm1,xmm0
        movaps xmm2,xmm1
        shufps xmm2,xmm2,02h
        addps xmm2,xmm1
        movss [esp+4],xmm2          ; a
        fld [esp+4]                 ; Result in ST(0)
        ret
    }
}
```

With the [__fastcall calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cpp/fastcall) you eliminate the last remaining stack overhead. The arguments are now passed in the ECX and EDX registers. But then you have no more memory for the result. My suggestion: Use a global variable for this.

```
float dummy;                        // global
__declspec(naked) float __fastcall dot(vec3 &a,vec3 &b) // fastcall, global variable
{
    _asm
    {
        movups xmm0,[ecx]           ; a
        movups xmm1,[edx]           ; b
        mulps xmm0,xmm1
        movaps xmm1,xmm0
        shufps xmm1,xmm1,0b1h
        addps xmm1,xmm0
        movaps xmm2,xmm1
        shufps xmm2,xmm2,02h
        addps xmm2,xmm1
        sub esp, 4
        movss [dummy],xmm2
        fld [dummy]
        add esp, 4
        ret
    }
}
```

Some people don't like global variables and I'm not sure, if you get trouble when using threads. Using the stack is a little bit cumbersome, since Windows does not know a red zone like Linux.

```
__declspec(naked) float __fastcall dot(vec3 &a,vec3 &b) // fastcall, stack access
{
    _asm
    {
        movups xmm0,[ecx]           ; a
        movups xmm1,[edx]           ; b
        mulps xmm0,xmm1
        movaps xmm1,xmm0
        shufps xmm1,xmm1,0b1h
        addps xmm1,xmm0
        movaps xmm2,xmm1
        shufps xmm2,xmm2,02h
        addps xmm2,xmm1
        sub esp, 4
        movss [esp],xmm2
        fld [esp]
        add esp, 4
        ret
    }
}
```

Why not use a macro? Why not align the vectors to use faster instructions (e.g. `MOVAPS`)? Here is a program that shows the use of an assembly block as macro:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef __declspec(align(16)) float vec3[4];    // https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cpp/align-cpp#vclrf_declspecaligntypedef

    #define dotproduct(dest,a,b) __asm  \
        { \
            __asm movaps xmm0,[a]       \
            __asm movaps xmm1,[b]       \
            __asm mulps xmm0,xmm1       \
            __asm movaps xmm1,xmm0      \
            __asm shufps xmm1,xmm1,0b1h \
            __asm addps xmm1,xmm0       \
            __asm movaps xmm2,xmm1      \
            __asm shufps xmm2,xmm2,02h  \
            __asm addps xmm2,xmm1       \
            __asm movss [dest],xmm2     \
        }

    int main ( void )
    {
        vec3 f1 = {1.0,2.0,3.0};
        vec3 f2 = {5.0,6.0,8.0};
        float R;

        dotproduct (R,f1,f2)

        printf ("%f\n",R);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but you have not answered the question. What if I really need the address of that variable?  What kind of operator does MASM provide for that?